# Changing color of table column text when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, html-table

I have a table where per row the first column is a checkbox and the remaining columns are text.  What I'd like to do is retroactively change the color of the text in columns 2:n for any rows where the checkbox is checked.

I'm using jQuery (and trying to refresh my knowledge of it) so a solution using this would be preferred but straight JS is also AOK.

Solution Found:

```
$("input:checked").each(function(idx) {
   $(this).parent().siblings('td').css("color", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UPbsC/6/) that turns the [sibling](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) `<td>` elements red when a checkbox is checked and turns them white when it's unchecked.

With this basic HTML,

```
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

And this Javascript.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click( function(e) {
            var bgColor = $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked' ? '#f00' : '#fff';

            $(this).parent().siblings('td').css('background', bgColor);   
        }); 
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: He asked for the columns to change colors, not the rows.

Comment: I assumed he meant the columns following the checkbox that was checked.  Maybe he can clarify.

Comment: Yep, I think you're right. I need to stop reading the questions here so quickly.

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone :)

Comment: Right - mblase75 is correct, that's not quite what I'm looking for.  What I want is an arbitrary event (e.g. some other control elsewhere on the page, document load, whatever) that will identify all of the checked rows and turn the text fields inside the other TD elements a different color.

I tried using something along what you showed, but it didn't work yet (note: In this example I'm just using your css command and not actually changing the text color):
 $(input:checked).parent.siblings('td').css('background',bgColor);